Restore Instance State without calling onCreate after rotation
I am working on an app to keep track of scores in a grid like format. I am using Kotlin and Room Database to store everything (playerId, gameInstanceId...). The storing works perfectly fine and every value is correctly assigned to a specific player in an specific round of a game. Now in the onCreate function i create a new unique ID for the gameInstance that just got started. The issue now is that if the screen gets rotated a new unique ID gets created and there the instance state is not here anymore. What could be a good solution to kind of outsource the creation of a new UI if it is really a new game and on the other hand be able to tell if the player wants to continue a already started gameInstance with an ID that exists and then based on that ID rebuild the gridlayout and continue the game. (As mention through the ID i can get all data i need that is not the problem). I also want to be able to like pause the game and then go through a list of previous games (finished and unfinished) and then be able to continue playing an unfinished game.
I already asked every chatbot and the answer is always save and restore onInstanceState but it just wont work because of the Id problem. Somehow the gridlayout doesnt want to function like i want it to. If you have a better solution than the gridlayout that is also warmly welcome.

Why don't you do it in the view model?

I have a GameInstanceViewModel and GameInstanceViewModel Factory. In my case the ViewModel handels data related functions and calls the repository which then calls the DAO which then accesses the database. What specifically should i do there?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
